# Написание модулей для Moodle

Tags: moodle

Добро времени суток! Есть кто хоть как-то знаком с СДО Moodle? Кто может посоветовать написать как-либо доп. модуль  для этой системы, на форумах толком ничего не нашел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет, **wicS**!

Какая версия мудл?

По ссылке http://smuncertainty.blogspot.ru/2012_01_01_archive.html есть статьи на тему разработки для **Moodle 2.х**

В нете валяется книга **Moodle 1.9 Extension Development** издательства **packtpub**.

Вот примеры к книге - http://rusfolder.com/34136881

Имя файла:4244_Code.zip

Размер: 526.48 кб

Контрольная сумма (MD5): 5a222d13ad54b3f5c8289f63dba8c55b

Так что можно потихоньку разбираться.